# PulseAudio cannot read buffers at consistent rate

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

I want to record my microphone and process in real time, eg. show an oscilloscope view of the microphone signal.

I've tried 3 ways to get the data out of PulseAudio and they all perform the same.  I expect a smooth stream of binary but instead there's a pattern roughly like:  Hang for ~300ms, print a ton of output, repeat.
3 different ways, 2 different machines, same results.

The 1st way was `parec`.

The 2nd and 3rd way are hello worlds in C and Haskell, both using the `pulse-simple` library.

**C:** https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/parec-simple_8c-example.html#a7

**Haskell:**

```
import Sound.Pulse.Simple
import Control.Monad
import System.IO

main = do

  s <- simpleNew Nothing "example" Record Nothing
       "this is an example application"
       (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing


  forever $ do

  let numSamples = 4410
  xs <- simpleRead s $ numSamples :: IO [Float]

  putStrLn $ "hello"

  hFlush stdout
```

Flushing stdout in the loop body does not make a difference.
Adding a delay in the loop changes the performance but not to what I want.

Somehow the `pavucontrol` VU meter gets it right.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  I discovered that while `pavucontrol` is running, I get great results, both in my example programs and with `parec`.  Why??

Also, I looked at the source of `pavucontrol` and `parec` , and it turns out they both use the `asynchronous` API, and my 2 example programs use the `simple` API.  So, the issue is not entirely due to the use of 1 API or the other, since `parec` behaves like the example programs.

Comment: try posting to https://dsp.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `pa_simple_new`, set the `fragsize` field of the `pa_buffer_attr` argument to the wanted latency in bytes. PulseAudio will try to achieve that latency, but may not reach it depending on the hardware capabilities.

(pavucontrol probably asks for a low latency. PulseAudio tries to reach the lowest latency requested by all currently running programs, so that's why the recording latency is low when pavucontrol is running).

In C:

```
    pa_buffer_attr attr;
    attr.maxlength = (uint32_t) -1;
    attr.tlength = (uint32_t) -1;
    attr.prebuf = (uint32_t) -1;
    attr.minreq = (uint32_t) -1;
    attr.fragsize = 1600;

    pa = pa_simple_new(NULL,
                       argv[0],
                       PA_STREAM_RECORD,
                       NULL,
                       "record",
                       &ss,
                       NULL,
                       &attr,
                       &error);
```

See [LatencyControl](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/LatencyControl/) for more information. (Note that the `PA_STREAM_ADJUST_LATENCY` flag is automatically set when using the simple API).

This should give a smoother stream of samples, but because `pa_simple_read` is blocking (waits until the entire buffer can be filled), you'll still have added latency, even if you use a small buffer for reading. To get rid of this extra latency, you need to use the asynchronous API for non-blocking reads.